# Expo React Native: Code Splitting Incompatible Web Packages

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I have a component that uses [@stripe/stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native) named **NativeCheckout**.

This package does not work on web (Chrome), and when I import it I get an error:

> Failed to compile
> /home/joey/Projects/project/project_frontend/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/lib/module/components/StripeProvider.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../../package.json' in '/home/joey/Projects/project/project_frontend/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/lib/module/components'

So if I run it in my browser, I do not want this component. This component is only rendered on native apps. I have found three alternative ways to import the Component. If my code is working fine then I add any of the follow lines, the above error is happening. I thought this would not load in the problem code.

```js
const loadNative = async () => {
  await import("./NativeCheckout")
}
```

```js
const NativeCheckout = lazy(() => import("./NativeCheckout"));
```

```js
const NativeCheckout = lazy(() => import("./NativeCheckout"));
```

Does anyone know a way to make this work?

TIA

Comment: load this code from a different file extension. Checkout.native.js and Checkout.web.js for example

Comment: @brentvatne How do I use that then? `import Checkout from "./Checkout` and expo chooses based on those naming conventions?

Comment: yup exactly. more info on that here https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions